# need a equal code for docker run with maven to docker compose with maven

Tags: java, maven, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using the below command to build my maven project.

```
sudo docker run --rm --name mavenbuild -v /User/myname/.m2:/root/.m2 -v $(pwd):/usr/src/workdir -w /usr/src/workdir maven:3.3.3-jdk-8 mvn clean install
```

This command working fine.

Now I try to convert the same command to docker compose

```
version: "2.0"

services:

    mavenbuild:
        image: maven:3.3.3-jdk-8
        volumes:
            - /User/myname/.m2:/root/.m2
            - ./:/usr/src/workdir
        working_dir: /usr/src/workdir
        command : mvn clean install
```

But the docker compose not working in expected way. please tell me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: _"not working in expected way"_ -- you will have to explain clearly what this means.

Comment: BTW: Why are you running the image build under `root`?

Comment: @JimGarrison sorry for the non detailed one. now it working fine for me . I did the -> docker-compose rm then tried the up . it works fine.

Comment: @khmarbaise, I am new this docker world. I tried this as a example. please suggest me how to do this properly. My goal is , I just want o build my maven project with my existing repo and settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

It works fine , after docker-compose rm, I guess this cached the previous build. I came to know after seeing the docker documentation.